# Does galera cluster works in thecloud (Azure IAAS)

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, galera

We are moving our infrastructure into the cloud (Microsoft)

Our current MySQL master-Slave environments will be moved as Infrastructure as a service.

At the same time I have been asked to look to move some of our master-slave env into a cluster.
We do not have the budget for MySQL cluster
This is why I'm looking at the Galera Cluster

will Galera Cluster work on the cloud and specially in Microsoft AZURE (IAAS)

Anybody with experience on something similar

Thank you

Regards

Comment: yes it does. We did some PoCs with customerson Azure. The question is: Is any cloud solution the right place to put your synchronous Galera Cluster to...?

Comment: thank you ofr the answer. The choice of the cloud solution is not ours. at least I know now that  it is a possible solution for us. Thank you, Regards, PC

Comment: Does Azure understand how Galera works?  I am thinking of its backups not being quite like for regular MySQL.

Comment: We are going in Azure as IAAS and not as PAAS so in fact we are moving the all servers themselve into the cloud. We will be doing the backup the same way as on a regular server.

Comment: @RickJames what's the difference between MySQL backups and Galera backups? It's just the same with `mysqldump` or `xtrabackup`? Do I miss something?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov - Azure => Microsoft => Windows => Xtrabackup not available.  Ditto for some other *nix tools.  `mysqldump` will work.  `xtrabackup` could be run from a Docker, but that involves installing a non-Windows OS -- not likely to be allowed.

Comment: @FyodorGlebov - As for what I was thinking 3 years ago; hmmmm.  I would consider adding a node, let it sync up (SST), then take out a node to do backups.  Best to research what Azure does / does not do for you.